# AngularJS and Maps API: stop prompting for computer's location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I created my web application, in which I added a map and custom markers with the following Angular loop:

```
<map data-ng-model="mymap" zoom="4" center="[38.50, -95.00]" style="heigth:375px">
    <div ng-repeat="item in list">
    <marker position="[{{item.coordinates}}]" icon="./images/icon.png" 
                                            on-click="showInfoWindow('mbar')" />
        <info-window id="mbar" >
        <div>{{item.name}}</div>
        <div class="getdirections">
           <a ng-href="http://maps.google.com/?daddr={{item.coordinates}}">Map</a>
        </div>
        </info-window>
```

This part works correctly and the browser does not ask the authorization to collect the computer's location.
On a different page of the same website, I again show a map with custom marker with this simpler code:

```
<map data-ng-model="mymapdetail" zoom="11" center="{{selectedItem.coordinates}}">
    <marker position="{{selectedItem.coordinates}}" icon="./images/icon.png" />
```

In this second page, when I open it, all browsers detects that I am asking for computer's location. If I don't answer to the question, my custom marker is correctly shown. As soon as I answer, regardless of sharing or not my position, the marker disappears. I need to clear the cache to show the marker again. No errors appear in the console.

Where is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It seems I found the issue:</strike>
First snippet:

```
 <marker position="[{{item.coordinates}}]" ...
```

Second snippet:

```
<marker position="{{selectedItem.coordinates}}"
```

Square brackets are missing. <strike>For some reasons, even though the marker is correctly shown and the map correctly centered, the syntax requires [] around the coordinates. Maybe, not putting them triggers a request to the client in order to set a marker representing the current user's position.
Adding the brackets seemed to fix the issue and geolocalization doesn't show up anymore.</strike>

Adding square brackets is not a solution. Even though adding them resolves the issue, it actually causes a new one: the marker disappears after reloading the page. Removing the square brackets sends back to the prompt, but at least markers are correctly shown. In the first page, removing the brackets does not cause any error.